# NHunspell with Microsoft Word?

Tags: .net, ms-word, hunspell

Does anyone know if there is a way to integrate [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) with Microsoft Word?

I've been trying to find a way to use opensource spelling dictionaries with Microsoft Word to enable support for languages that currently do not have an option for spell checking directly from Microsoft. But have not been able to find any solution.

I work specifically with Khmer (I am one of the authors of the Khmer spelling checker dictionary for [Hunspell](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/khmersbbic)), and one of the reasons many do not use a spelling checker for Khmer is because it lacks support for Microsoft Word.  There have been attempts at Microsoft Word integration ([PAN Cambodia](http://panl10n.net/english/OutputsCambodia1.htm) has a spelling checker add-in for Word but it is so slow and inaccurate that it is basically unusable.

UPDATE: We were able to create a spelling checker for Khmer and Microsoft Word using NHunspell. You can download it [here](http://www.sbbic.org/2014/08/08/sbbic-khmer-spelling-checker-microsoft-word/) along with the [sourcecode](https://github.com/sbbic/sbbic-khmer-spelling-checker-for-ms-word) (which you could fork for another language).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the "Common SpellerApplication Programming Interface". Here is the official link about it: [The Microsoft Common Speller API (CSAPI) for Office spell checking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262605/en-us)

As you see, it's not really public, but the actual specification can be downloaded from here: http://spell.com.ru/dicts/csapi.pdf

If you're looking for a sample, google for "Interfacing an Irish Spellchecker to microsoft word 2000".

It's not a .NET interface, it's a DLL interface, sou you'll have to use some C/C++ or other language capable of exposing DLL exports somewhere in your program to be able to build a proxy to access .NET.